# Tkinter scrollbar slider does not move?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, slider, scrollbar

I am working on a GUI where pressing a certain button produces a pop-up window that should display a long, scrollable list of text. I'm using the text widget within the popup window to display this text.
I've added a scrollbar and it appears on the pop-up window just fine. However when you try to scroll, moving the slider on the scrollbar does nothing. The slider doesn't even move. But the text list will respond and scroll when I use the mouse-wheel. Please see the code below for the command "bib" that is assigned to my button:

```
def bib():
  root = tk.Tk()
  root.title("References")

  h=tk.Scrollbar(root)
  h.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
  v=tk.Scrollbar(root)

  t=tk.Text(root,width=90, wrap=tk.NONE, yscrollcommand=v.set)

  t.insert(tk.END,"number 1\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 2\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 1\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 2\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 1\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 2\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 1\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 2\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 1\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 2\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 1\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 2\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 1\n")
  t.insert(tk.END,"number 2\n")

  t.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
  t.configure(font=("Times New Roman", 10))
  v.config(command=t.yview)

  t.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbars and their associated widgets require two-way communication. You've created a one-way communication from the text widget to the scrollbar but not the other way around.

The command for the horizontal scrollbar needs to call the `xview` method of the scrollable widget, and the command for the vertical scrollbar needs to call the `yview` method.

Answer (score 0):

You create two `Scrollbar` - `h` and `v` - and you display first scrollbar `h` but you assign `Text` to second scrollbar `v` which you don't display.

You have to assign correct `Scrollbar` to `Text`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("References")

# rename `h` to `v`
v = tk.Scrollbar(root)    
v.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

# rename `v` to `h`
#h = tk.Scrollbar(root)

t = tk.Text(root,width=90, wrap=tk.NONE, yscrollcommand=v.set)

for _ in range(20):
    t.insert(tk.END,"number 1\n")
    t.insert(tk.END,"number 2\n")

t.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
t.configure(font=("Times New Roman", 10))

v.config(command=t.yview)

t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh my gosh that was it, thank you so much for catching that!!!